# C program with Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I am new to C and notice that when i run my code i am getting a Segmentation Fault and i dont know how to fix it...any help appreciated!

```
void getComment(unsigned int len, char *src) {
    unsigned int size;
    size = len – 4;
    char *comment = malloc(size+1);
    memcpy(comment, src, size);
    printf("%s\n", comment);
    return;
 }
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <str1> <str2>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    getComment(atoi(argv[1]), argv[2]);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: If `atoi` fails, what is `size`?

Comment: You also have a memory leak

Comment: `size = len – 4;` ← please explain

Comment: In any case, your "comment" is certainly not null-terminated properly. -> Undefined behaviour.

Comment: What do you pass as arguments to your program? What happens if `argv[1]` holds a number larger than the length of `argv[2]`?

Comment: You need to compile all your program with all warnings & debug info (e.g `gcc  -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then improve your code to get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** (`gdb` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many run time errors in it.

1. len -4 can return a negative value.
2. you can miss copying the last null character of incoming string into comment. that case comment will be no longer string and when you use %s it will give you error or garbage.

Better approach will be to check if :

```
if (size > 0 && size <= strlen(src) {
     memcpy(comment, src, size);
     comment[strlen(comment)] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but do you account for the fact, that strings in C are null-terminated? I.e. string `"abc"` really consists of 4 characters, `'a', 'b',  'c' and '\0'`. When you use `memcpy` you might be missing on the last null. And `printf` assumes that string is null terminated as well, null signifying the place where it has to stop printing output.

C has a number of functions that work with strings and account for null character. Try looking up the following functions: `strlen`, `strcpy` (instead of `memcpy`).

Comment: He probably knows this. (`malloc(size+1)`) I assume he expects `malloc` to fill the memory with zero.